# How does a custom module architecture work?

Tags: theming

I am a beginner with D8 and I need to create a module with a custom form.
I created the module and created the form. I also created a custom block in order to render the form (the plugin block and the form are in the same module). Is everything ok ?

I don't understand how twig works in this case. On my admin panel I can add the block on a specific page. But can I modify the template of the form by creating templates files in my module ? I'm I obliged to use the block ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You need to define your templates in `hook_theme` and then call those themes when you build the render array in your controller `['#theme' => 'template_defined_in_hook']`. See https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/create-custom-twig-templates-for-custom-module

Comment: Thank You for your reply. I already followed the Drupal guide you gave me. So if I understand correctly, I can call the template for the form on my form controller and same for the block ?

Comment: I've this for frontend templates, like blocks. The Form API requires a very specific, pre-defined markup to work properly (div containers, attributes, field names,...), I've no experience designing custom forms beyond using the default Form API render elements (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/elements/8.2.x)

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I'll have a look at the ressources.